# Video is corrupting when compiled with mxmlc but not Flash IDE

Tags: apache-flex, flash, video, actionscript-3, mxmlc

I have movie clips containing FLV video sequences.

When this FLV plays in a SWF compiled from mxmlc, the video is completely corrupted - all different coloured blocks. If I compile from the IDE the video plays fine.

It's a bit more involved than this:

- If I play multiple copies of the same FLV at the same time, they're fine, whereas if I play various FLVs at the same time, they corrupt.
- They don't always corrupt on every playthrough - it's not consistent.
- If I zoom into the corrupted video, or move the player window, the corrupted image remains intact, i.e. it's not like a screen redrawing error where the corrupted area will often change or clear.

Does anyone know of any Flex compiler options, or SWC authoring strategies to get around this?

Comment: Why are you compiling flvs into the SWF?  Wouldn't you want then to be external assets?

Comment: This is a game where the FLVs are used for interface effects - it's not video content per se, like a video player.

Comment: That makes a little more sense, then.  My best advice is to be sure to file a bug at bugs.adobe.com and/or provide the code / assets to create a reproducible case.  here.

Comment: @approxiblue - what worked was exporting a SWF containing the FLV assets from the Flash IDE, with the assets set with Actionscript linkage IDs. Then loading this SWF at runtime into the game SWF compiled with mxmlc - the FLV assets could then be instantiated with AS. This question is 5+ years old, and hopefully mxmlc, or the new compiler - whatever that's called - have been fixed now

Comment: I'm only editing because of the recent bounty. @how does tarling's update work for you?

Comment: Which version of Flex are you using? Have you tried getting the latest Apache Flex SDK (which contains the latest mxmlc compiler) by installing it from http://flex.apache.org/installer.html

Comment: I'm using the last version downloaded from official site. It seems like an old bug - http://flexcoders.10928.n7.nabble.com/FLV-bug-using-Flex-compiler-in-an-actionscript-project-with-flv-s-in-swc-s-td37297.html . When I compile the same code from Flash it shows everything perfectly so it might be something wrong with Flex.

Comment: I'm using the last version of mxmlc - the problem is still there. It's most obviously a bug of Flex, but may be somebody knows a workaround without using IDE.

Comment: I've tried these versions - all the same bad result: Apache Flex 4.14.1; Flex 4.6.0, AIR 18.0; Flex 3.6A, AIR 1.5.3